# Partial parameters are duplicated

Tags: python, kivy, partial

I am creating `on_press` callbacks for button behavior objects inside a loop and for some reason all of the parameters for the partial stay the same as the parameters for the last partial created. 
shortened example of creation:
(button is a class that implements button behaviour)

```
for button in list:
    button.on_press=partial(my_func, button, button.arg1, button.arg2)
```

the problem is that the arguments `arg1` and `arg2` stay the same as the last iteration of the loop instead of being updated. so when I press the buttons (doesn't matter which one) the callback is called as if I pressed the last button.

why does this happen / how can I fix this?

Comment: In the snippet arguments `arg1`, `arg2` don't change.

Comment: Because _you_ never change `arg1` or `arg2`.

Comment: Rather, `button.arg1` and `button.arg2` are evaluated when the `partial` object is *defined*, not when you actually click the button.

Comment: Are you sure `arg1`, `arg2` are not the same for all buttons from `list`? `print` in every iteration will show it.

Comment: @leaf well not quite, I do change them as you can tell by the updated snippet. I do change them in the actual code (which is too long to post a meaningful part here).